# Javascript csom to get lookup/person or group value

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom, jsom

I am trying to get values of few lookup columns and person or group column of  my list using the below code

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web=context.get_web(); 
var list=web.get_lists(); 
var targetList;
targetList = list.getByTitle("list name");
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+myID+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
window.collListItem = targetList.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(collListItem);              
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
function onQuerySucceeded(sender,args)
{

 var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
 while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
 var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
 var a =  oListItem.get_item('lookup column').get_lookupValue();
 var b = oListItem.get_item('person or group').get_lookupValue();
}
 function onQueryFailed(sender,args){alert('failed');}
```

But it throws error

```
The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

How to get the value of those columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the lookup column in the `<ViewFields>` section!
like this :

```
<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='" + lookupFieldName + "' LookupId='TRUE' /></ViewFields></View>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! but why doesn't SharePoint fetch the lookup values & person or group values?  Looks like the above query will fetch only the columns that were given in FieldRef.  What if I need to get the values of all columns(lookups & person or group inclusive) of a list item? Do i have to mention all those columns under FieldRef?

Comment: Once you use the ViewFields, you will be getting what you ask for. If you need anything you can use undefined CAML Query (dont't specify a query - According to Microsoft). I would suggest using this tool that will help you build your query better http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/

Good Luck!